# Javasccript or angularJS : is to possible to get Browser TAB click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking for a event like when when come back to a tab?

for example: I have opened four tab in the same browser with same url:

like: `http://127.0.0.1:/blabla`
`http://127.0.0.1:/blabla` `http://127.0.0.1:/blabla` `http://127.0.0.1:/blabla`

If i switched to a tab to another tab, i dont want that event. when i back to a tab, i want to get the event to refresh the page.

My objective is, when i back to the `http://127.0.0.1:/blabla`, the page should automatically reload, nothing else

Comment: Are you doing this for learning or for a real project? It could be a bit annoying for user experience, escpecially when connexion is not great. If the goal is to keep the data up to date, solutions like a websocket could be better (more complicated, I know)

Comment: I am doing for real project but i couldnt implement it with websocket

Answer (score 1):

You can capture onfocus event of window and try to reload the page.

```
window.onfocus and window.onblur
```

should work for you and then try to reload the page